# Bad Auth with mongoose when deploying NestJS app on Heroku

Tags: heroku, mongoose, nestjs

I'm trying to deploy my NestJS app on Heroku but now all of the sudden app is throwing `Bad Auth` error.

On the development it's all working fine.

#### This is the error I'm getting:

[image]

---

I'm storing the credentials in `.env`

[image]

Are these constants populated by Heroku with some unexpected values?

---

And I'm allowing the connection from every IP address:
[image]

What is going on and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same trouble, the solution for me was to put the whole link to connect in an environment variable instead of just the secret. I was using node, express, mongoose and MongoDB Atlas, so for me it was:

```
//on .env file
ATLAS_CONNECT=mongodb+srv://yourusername:yoursecret@cluster0.mre5gvd.mongodb.net/yourDBname
```

```js
//to connect
mongoose.connect(process.env.ATLAS_CONNECT);
```